# Cloning XBox360 with dd

Tags: hard-drive, clone, xbox-360

I see a couple of tutorials here on using `dd`, but I wanted to ask to make 100% sure.

Can I clone my XBox360 hdd over to a larger hdd using dd? I just dont want to lose my current data thats there. Also, is it really as simple as

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc
```

If it matters, Im running Lubuntu 14.04 64bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends. If you have two original Xbox 360 drives you can clone one to the other and everything should work just fine.

Using a regular 2,5" drive in an Xbox 360 does not work. Unless you have a drive that can be *"hacked"*, e.g. you copy the *"security sector"* with a DOS tool onto the drive's firmware so that the Xbox 360 detects it as a legit drive.

- No, this is not about modifying the Xbox firmware for warezing games (you're console might not get banned, but it's possible).
- Yes you need a DOS boot disk/drive and a machine that boots legacy. Try to avoid FreeDOS if you're unsure, because I found other programs for modifying firmware that really rely on DOS boot disks the way Windows 9x creates them.

I have 2 "hacked" drives and backup one to the other using `dd` without issues. (Just dd'ing to the other drive didn't work.)

I'm not sure if linking to a certain site that provides the tool and sectors for different disk sizes (including a list of compatible disks) is legal. Search for terms like *Xbox 360 hddhackr* and stay away from typical download fraud. Using standard drives with the Xbox One seems to be [easier](http://withinrafael.com/taking-a-peek-at-xbox-one-formatted-disks-in-windows/).

**Note:** `dd` puts a lot of stress on a drive. If you have a failing drive, try to copy only the necessary data through the Xbox user interface onto USB storage first if that is possible.

Comment: You still get an upvote, but for a failing drive, I would use `ddrescue` (actually: I never use `dd`, only `ddrescue`...)

Comment: @Fabby Thanks, I haven't looked into ddrescue before.

Comment: @LiveWireBT I would have figured that an exact clone would have been sufficient. BTW, my current HHD is not failing...just getting low on space. I have not addressed the issue but will post back or mark as answered whenever I get to it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would be very careful when cloning disks with dd, as you have to pay attention to the disc's labels, as described by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874441/hard-drive-clone-using-dd). I don't know exactly how the XboX handles this, but I prefer using [Clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/) for performing such tasks. It features a textual user interface and a beginner mode for easy cloning disks. Furthermore, it also offers a special mode for cloning data from one hdd to a larger one.

Nevertheless, I have already copied Cubian OS images to my Cubieboard's SD card using the dd command described by you. Moreover, I have also used the bs argument for specifying how many bytes can be read and write at a time as well as the argument conv=notrunc,noerror,sync for ignoring erros, for avoiding truncating the output as well as for making sure the operations have finished.